# Dynamically replace elements using jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, jsx

I'm having an array `data.info` that is being updated over time and I'm trying to replace placeholder rendered elements with another. So by default `app.js` looks like this

```
return (
    <Fragment>
        {data.info.map((index) => {
            return <Typography key={index} variant="h6" className={classes.title}>Demo</Typography>
                })}
    </Fragment>
)
```

Also I have a hook with async function to subscribed to `data.info.length`.

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        if (!initialRender.current) {
            if (data.info.length!==0) {
            for (let i = data.info.length-iScrollAmount+1 ; i < data.info.length+1; i++) {
                firstAsync(i)
            }
        }

        } else {
            initialRender.current = false
        }
    },
    [data.info.length]
)

async function firstAsync(id) {
    let promise = new Promise(() => {
            setTimeout(() => console.log(document.getElementById(id)), 500)
    });
    }
```

With `document.getElementById()` and `id` I can get to every element that was rendered and change it. And here goes the problems.

1. I'm using `material-ui` so I can't get to `<Typography/>` because it is transformed into `<h6/>`. Probably that is not a problem since I need to replace contents, so I can find `parent` element and remove all children. Is that way correct?
2. After I delete children how do I add content using `jsx`? What I mean is that in async function I'll get an array that I want to use in new element `<NewCard/>` to dynamically put into `<Fragment/>`. Yet I did not find any example how to do that.

Comment: You should be rendering your React components with State, so all you do is update the state, your components will then automatically shadow your state.

Comment: A todo list dynamically updates, so try following this -> https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/build-a-simple-todo-app-with-react-561579b39ad1   Actually if your using hooks, this might be better -> https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-todo-list-with-react-hooks-ebaa4e3db3b/

Comment: @Keith thank you! I'll check it

Answer (score 1):

React does not encourage the practice of manipulating the HTML DOM nodes directly.

Basically you need to see 2 things.

1. `State` which is a special variable whose value is retained on subsequent refresh. Change in reference in this variable will trigger component and its children a refresh/re-render.
2. `Props` which is passed to every `Component` and is read only. Changing in props causes refresh of component by default.

In your example, based on `data.info` you want to render `Typography` component.

**Solution**

1. First thing is your map function is incorrect. First parameter of `map` function is item of list and second is index. If you are not sure if `info` will always be present in `data`, you may want to have a null check as well.

`{(data.info || []).map((info, index) => {
   return <Typography key={index} variant="h6" className={classes.title}>{info.text}</Typography>
})}`

2. You should be passing `info` from `map` to `Typography` component. Or use `info` value in content of `Typography` as shown above.
3. Update `data.info` and `Typography` will update automatically. For this, please make sure, `data.info` is a component state and not a plain variable. Something like

`const [data, setData] = React.useState({});`

And when you have value of `data` (assuming from API), then

`setData(responseApi);`

Comment: nope, there is no mistake. By default all mapped list items consist of placeholder items `<Typography />` and after I receive an array from `firstAsync()` I want to replace these with another element `<NewCard/>` that actually uses data stored within `data.info` array value.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to change `DOM Nodes` directly in React, and you need to let React do the rendering for you and you just tell react what to do.

in your case you need to define a React `State` for your `data` and set your `state` inside your `firstAsync` function and then use your `state` to render whatever html element or React component which you want

Comment: I've seen that `useState()` could be used for data, but is there any way to define state of an element? I dont quite understant how do I use it in `return` section, guess I need `useReducer` here

Comment: My guess based on your comment is you don't need to use reducer , you only have two ```state``` in your app , one for default and one for after ```firstAsync``` function call.

Comment: So you need to have one ```useState``` for your ```data``` and another for example for ```isNewCard``` which is a ```boolean``` and try to ```set``` ```isNewCard``` in your ```firstAsync``` function. then decide if ```isNewCard``` was true display your ```<NewCard />``` Component otherwise show your default components